# How to fix OpenLayers plugin for QGIS Master?

Tags: qgis, qgis-openlayers-plugin

I can't get the OpenLayers plugin to work in QGIS Master (1.9), I loaded the repository successfully, but the plugin doesn't come up as an option anywhere.  I'm new to this, but have tried to make sense of several fixes (here: http://hub.qgis.org/issues/6979).  I don't know where/how to save the patch/file. Any help is appreciated, I have to have some kind of streets basemap by the morning.

Thanks!!
Brian

Answer (score 3):

have not used it myself, but there is a fix of the plugin for the new upcoming version 2.0 of qgis
http://www.qgis.nl/2013/06/30/english-temporary-fix-for-openlayers-plugin/?lang=en

Comment: Can confirm that this works here (today at least), Ubuntu/QGIS Master.

Answer (score 1):

QGIS Master is currently undergoing major changes for the upcoming QGIS 2.0 release. As a part of that, all plugins have to be re-written.

Sourcepole (the maintainer of OpenLayers Plugin) have promised to fix the plugin until the release, which might take until September. Until then, you have to stick to QGIS Lisboa to have the plugin running.

The current bug trac is http://hub.qgis.org/issues/8059

You can find the whole discussion about OpenLayers for the 2.0 release here: http://osgeo-org.1560.x6.nabble.com/Openlayers-plugin-in-2-0-Was-QGIS-2-0-release-and-plugins-td5060364.html

Comment: does that mean that qgis 2.0 will not be available before autum?

Comment: No sure yet.  It depends, there is a few bug that need to be squashed first.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!! Any help pointing me toward another streets basemap option in the meantime...I need the Atlas Generator from the master version.

Comment: If you are on Windows, you can pick an earlier version here: http://qgis.org/downloads/weekly/ and **do** **not** update afterwards (what I am practicing for some weeks now ;-)